# Increase number of practical microcontroller outputs (x when pin 1 is powered, y when pin 2 is powered, and z when both are)?

Tags: microcontroller

Is there any way to make a circuit that powers (only) x part of it when pin 1 is powered, (only) y part of it when pin 2 is powered, and only z part of it when both are?
I am new at electronics...i do not know.

Comment: You question is unclear. Please explain what you want to "power" (or do you want to enable something? Controlling the power of a circuit section or enabling something might be totally different depending on the requirements). Please explain if my understanding is correct: you have two microcontroller outputs (able to represent [four states in binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary)) and you want to decode the states to get three signals (those three that are able to control other sections)? Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: As for the "decoding". If my understanding is correct, you want [a 2-to-4 decoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decoder#1-of-n_decoder) (look at the truth table and the schematic of the image). A BCD to decimal decoder is able to do this, like a [CMOS 4028](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4028b.pdf) which is available as an IC already.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and thanks for your answer, and it is more accurate for the question i asked, but for what i needed it Arun Joe's answer is more usefull. Sorry for not asking exactly what i needed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hi there are lots of GPIO EXPANDER ICs available in market which can be used for this purpose.